# FileStream delimiter?

Tags: c#, filestream

I have a large file with (text/Binary) format.

file format: (*`0` represent a byte*)

```
00000FileName0000000Hello
World
world1
...
0000000000000000000000
```

Currently i'm using `FileStream` and i want to read the Hello.

I Know where Hello start, and it ends with a 0x0D 0x0A.

I also need to go back if the words is not equal to Hello.

How can i read until a carriage return?

is there any `PEEK` like function in `FileStream` so i can move back the read pointer`?

is `FileStream` even a good choice in this case?

Comment: Does the 0 represent a byte?

Comment: Its binary file that also contains text

Comment: @UmarJamil YES I will edit it

Comment: "I Know where Hello start,"-where does it start then?

Comment: the problem is mostly that as it is a binary file you can't make sure where hello stands,.... as there is no new line to differentate between things,.. .  so in essence you ened to read in the whole file into a string and then search for Hello in the string.

Comment: @Giorgi The first four bytes indicate the where Hello starts

Comment: @Giorgi my bad, the first four bytes indicate where the word starts, and i want know if the word is equal Hello

Comment: @RayOldProf: So just do a ReadAllBytes call and navigate to that index. Hello consists of 5 characters you don't even need carriage return

Comment: @Giorgi Its a very large file, cant use ReadAllBytes

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [FileStream.Seek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek(v=vs.90).aspx) to change the read/write position.

Comment: If the stream is seekable.

Comment: Thank you @taffer, make sure to check the CanSeek property.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted - OP has specified he is reading from a file which will be seekable. This in conjunction with the ReadByte or Read methods can be used to check for "Hello" & use Seek to move back if necessary.

Comment: Thank you @PaulF. Yes, I expect you to know the binary's length, as you specified the complete format. So just seek to the correct position, read the required number of bytes and eventually move back. You can't just skip random bytes of which you don't know the length in advance, that's why in most binary formats, before the data, the length is specified.

Comment: The first four bytes can be read & combined in the correct order (would need to know if stored as Little Endian or Big Endian for that) - seek to that offset & read 5 bytes & compare to Hello - if so carry on reading byte by byte until carriage return or Seek(0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BinaryReader` for reading binary content; however, it uses an inner buffer so you cannot rely the underlying `Stream.Position` anymore, because it can read more bytes in the background than you want. But you can re-implement its needed methods:

```
private byte[] ReadBytes(Stream s, int count)
{
    buffer = new byte[count];
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return buffer;
    }

    // reading one byte
    if (count == 1)
    {
        int value = s.ReadByte();
        if (value == -1)
            threw new IOException("Out of stream");

        buffer[0] = (byte)value;
        return buffer;
    }

    // reading multiple bytes
    int offset = 0;
    do
    {
        int readBytes = s.Read(buffer, offset, count - offset);
        if (readBytes == 0)
            threw new IOException("Out of stream");

        offset += readBytes;
    }
    while (offset < count);

    return buffer;
}

public int ReadInt32(Stream s)
{
    byte[] buffer = ReadBytes(s, 4);
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
}

// similarly, write ReadInt16/64, etc, whatever you need
```

Assuming that you are on the start position, you can write a `ReadString`, too:

```
private string ReadString(Stream s, char delimiter)
{
    var result = new List<char>();
    int c;
    while ((c = s.ReadByte()) != -1 && (char)c != delimiter)
    {
        result.Add((char)c);
    }

    return new string(result.ToArray());
}
```

Usage:

```
FileStream fs = GetMyFile(); // todo
if (!fs.CanSeek)
    throw new NotSupportedException("sorry");

long posCurrent = fs.Position;          // save current position
int posHello = ReadInt32(fs);           // read position of "hello"
fs.Seek(posHello, SeekOrigin.Begin);    // seeking to hello
string hello = ReadString(fs, '\n');    // reading hello
fs.Seek(posCurrent, SeekOrigin.Begin);  // seeking back
```